# CouchCMS Blog index items to display inline (blog_list.html)

Tags: inline, display

I've used Couch CMS to create a blog page with index of articles.

I've used Couch for blog systems before and the blog index item always displays underneath each other. However, this time they must display next to each other. I've tried so many things, but the index items remains under each other oppose to next to each other. The website is based on bootstrap, but the columns just keep on stacking on top of each other.

Can someone please help?

URL: https://legacyeb.co.za/news.php

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just make sure the couch page open and page close tags are in the correct place.
Everything in between the tags gets repeated with the blog index.